# Running MongoDB from Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker

I just downloaded Docker and created the MongoDB container on it.

I have successfully created the container and it is working on the port 168.192.99.100:32728 on my local machine. I'm confused how should I run mongo on my machine?

For example if we create the SQL container we can connect to the port using MySQL Workbench. How do i do something similar for Mongo?

Comment: "mongod" cmd should suffice

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

Running the mongo-client on your host-system (requires install of mongo-client):

> mongo --host 168.192.99.100 --port 32728

see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo

or maybe the simpler option of attaching to the docker-container with the running mongodb-server which already should have a mongo-client installed:

> docker exec -it "name of container" mongo

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/